# Can you use Jenkins to deploy to Weblogic and then run SoapUI tests against the deployment?

Tags: java, jenkins, weblogic, soapui

I have a Jenkins server setup to build a project and deploy it to Weblogic. I would then like to run suite of SoapUI tests against the deployed project. I can do this manually, but I would like some way of automating it and reporting it via Jenkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WebLogic deployment from Jenkins, have a look at this [WebLogic Deployer Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WebLogic+Deployer+Plugin).

What kind of build tool are you using for your project? If your project is a Maven project, Maven integration is described [here](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html). There's another one on [GitHub](https://github.com/redfish4ktc/maven-soapui-extension-plugin) with further enhancements.

Create a Maven job on Jenkins and configure the soapUI plugin to produce junit style reports. That's all.

**+** And searching Stackoverflow doesn't hurt :) [How to integrate soapUI with jenkins / hudson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648244/how-to-integrate-soapui-with-jenkins-hudson)

Comment: The problem with these examples is that I need to delay the soapUi tests until after the install step of Maven and it's been deployed to the weblogic server and started up.

Comment: Maven install compiles, builds and packages your project, with the goal to create a "deployable" artifact. Or do you don't use Maven at all? In any case you want somehow run your web service (or whatever) soapUI tests against the deployed endpoints, right?
You could put the soapUI project and settings files in a separate Maven project/module, since runing the soapUI Web Service or whatever tests does not need rebuilding your code project.