# Automation tests using Cucumber, SoapUI and Selenium

Tags: selenium, jenkins, cucumber, soapui

I'd like to use Cucumber linked with SoapUI and Selenium in order to create an automation functional test.
I only found one website about it, describing that first I have to create a SoapUI project and save it as a .xml file. Then I should include this file into the test project using Cucumber and Selenium.

My first question is what configuration do I have to do for that ? (in the pom.xml file when using Maven for example or in any configuration file for Jenkins)

My second and last question is : if I launch every night with Jenkins (let's say that as an example) my tests, do I have to launch first the SoapUI project and import it again in the test project to run my tests in a good way ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: I would not use soapui with cucumber. soapui has it's own test framework and cucumber has (whether java, ruby, or js based) soap and rest clients. Can't you just call soapui from jenkins? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648244/how-to-integrate-soapui-with-jenkins-hudson#6649134

Comment: The fact is that the company where I work already uses SoapUI to test its API. And, even if it wants to use the new BDD way to test application, they would also like to keep using SoapUI.

Comment: Life would be so much easier if we didn't have to contort our work to fit the insistence of how it gets done. Probably the fallacy of sunk costs.

Comment: Anything is possible! Unfortunately, I have more questions about your approach than you do. Try something, if it does not work, come back with more specific questions. I can tell you the first question you will have to answer is: What is going to be the main framework that runs all your tests?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use REST Assured for you API testing.

Use cucumber for your BDD statement, use java for there step definition and REST Assured for all the API request stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your automation with well written Gherkin and you'll need no other documentation. Think about that. BDD (specification by example) is a requirements approach, not a testing approach.