# Web Service test automation with Selenium with Cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am working on a test automation project where I am using Selenium with Cucumber with Maven dependencies. 
I need to automate web service requests. We do have SoapUI pro in place. 
Is it possible to automate web service using soapUI api? If yes, How?
If No, what is the workaround? 
What other test automation web service tools can be integrated with selenium?

Ideally, we want everything to be Behavior driven.

This is the automation goal :
Cucumber > Selenium > UI
Cucumber > Selenium > Web Service (SoapUI or whatever)

I am new to this. My question may not be valid and I have done some research and did not get any outcomes which supports my goal.

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Selenium isn't a test tool. It's a library that allows you to build a test framework. Find the right library for every interface - in this case you want a rest client library, or if in-process, use mocks.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814049/automation-tests-using-cucumber-soapui-and-selenium?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Stop right there.

[Generate a WebServices client](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/Examples_glassfish6.html) and ride with Cucumber straight on the API just like any Unit test. Good bye Selenium/SoapUI, not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium tests and Webservice tests are complimentary to each other. The only time you will see them in tandem is submitting a request via webservice and verifying the result on UI with selenium, or vice-versa.

For webservice testing in java, you will have to use other java libraries depending on the kind. You can use libraries like HTTPClient for Rest or SAAJ for SOAP but there are others too.

Personally, I love SoapUI but havent gotten to using it in a java project. A simple search returned this :https://www.soapui.org/developers-corner/integrating-with-soapui.html . Looks pretty straightforward.